# Acessing struct fields within an assembly X64 function

Tags: assembly, syntax, 64-bit, att

Is it possible to access directly struct fields within an assembly function? And how can I access via assembly an global variable?

In inline assembly on intel syntax I can do this:

```
 struct str
 {
   int a;
   int b;
 }
 int someGlobalVar;

 __declspec(naked)   void __fastcall func(str * r)
 {
    __asm
    {
       mov dword ptr [ecx].a, 2
       mov dword ptr [ecx].b,someGlobalVar
    }
}
```

How do I do this  in a assembly x64 function (not inline), with ATT syntax (gcc), if it's not possible how do I do this in an inline function?

Answer (score 3):

For this any many similar problems, the easiest solution is to write an example in C that does what you want, then use `gcc -m64 -S ...` to generate assembler source, and then use that source as a template for your own assembly code.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} S;

int foo(const S *s)
{
    int c = s->a + s->b;

    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
    S s = { 2, 2 };

    printf("foo(%d, %d) = %d\n", s.a, s.b, foo(&s));

    return 0;
}
```

If we generate asm using `gcc -Wall -O1 -m64 -S foo.c -o foo.S` we get the following for the "foo" function:

```
.globl _foo
_foo:
LFB3:
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
    movl    (%rdi), %eax
    addl    4(%rdi), %eax
    leave
    ret
```

As you can see, `movl   (%rdi), %eax` gets the element a of the struct, and then `addl  4(%rdi), %eax` adds element b, and the function result is returned in `%eax`.

Comment: The problem with that, is that kind of code is that if the struct layout changes, i've to go the the assembly code to update it, the idea of using that kind of code is to avoid that kind of stuff. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @DVD: ah - you mean you want to use the actual struct element names as offsets within your asm code ?